# How to get more information on what AOS is doing during startup?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I noticed very different execution times for AOS startup on different machines. This is to be expected because of different hardware sizings but it got me curious of what AOS is doing and what (sometimes) takes so long.

**Is there a log-file where I can monitor what AOS is doing during startup?** Or any other method of monitoring the AOS startup?
I'm interested in both AX2009 and AX2012 if there is any difference.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user [*Trace Parser*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axperf/archive/2011/09/06/walk-through-the-major-features-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-trace-parser-part-2.aspx) to analyze Event Trace Data from windows perfmon.

Capture traces on AOS with perfmon. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axperf/archive/2011/11/18/collect-ax-2012-event-traces-with-windows-performance-monitor.aspx for example.

Answer (score 2):

One big difference you may experience is when debug is enabled or not at AOS side.

When you start the AOS, it gets the AX assemblies compiled in CIL (dll and modules) under XppIL folder.

If debug is activated on AOS, it gets a text file with xpp extension under XppIL\Source for each method. So it might take a lot more time.